# Resolving params in C#

Tags: c#, parameters

What are the rules when resolving variable number of parameters passed by `params`?

Suppose, that I have the code:

```
public void Method(params object[] objects) { }

public void Method(IMyInterface intf, params object[] objects) { }
```

How is `Method(a, b, c)` resolved, if a is a IMyInterface? Can I be sure, that C# will always try to select most matching overload?

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is answered by the C# language spec:

> **7.5.3.1 Applicable function member**
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, if MP is applicable in its normal form and MQ has a
>     params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then MP is
>     better than MQ.
> - Otherwise, if MP has more declared parameters than MQ, then MP is
>     better than MQ. This can occur if both methods have `params` arrays
>     and are applicable only in their expanded forms.
>
> [...]

In your example both overloads would be applicable only in their expanded forms. Since the second has more declared parameters it would be *better*.

In the context of the spec, one overload being *better* than all the others means that the compiler selects it to bind the call, as would happen in the example under discussion (if no one overload is better than all the others, the result is a compile-time error due to ambiguity).

Comment: What is expanded form of method parameters?

Comment: @gmailuser: In layman's terms, you are using the "expanded form" if removing the `params` from the method definition would cause the method call to not compile. Taking the first overload, `Method(new object[] { "foo" })` is the normal form because the formal argument is an `object[]` and that is what you are passing. `Method("foo")` is the expanded form because you rely on the compiler to create the `object[]` for you, and it would not be possible without the `params`.

Answer (score 3):

See also [C# Spec. 17.5.1.4 regarding Parameter arrays](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/17.5.1.4.htm)

> When performing overload resolution, a method with a parameter array
>   may be applicable either in its normal form or in its expanded form
>   (§14.4.2.1). 2 The expanded form of a method is available only if the
>   normal form of the method is not applicable and only if a method with
>   the same signature as the expanded form is not already declared in the
>   same type.

**Example**

```
using System;  
class Test  
{  
   static void F(params object[] a) {  
      Console.WriteLine("F(object[])");  
   }  
   static void F() {  
      Console.WriteLine("F()");  
   }  
   static void F(object a0, object a1) {  
      Console.WriteLine("F(object,object)");  
   }  
   static void Main() {  
      F();  
      F(1);  
      F(1, 2);  
      F(1, 2, 3);  
      F(1, 2, 3, 4);  
   }  
}
```

produces the output:

```
F();  
F(object[]);  
F(object,object);  
F(object[]);  
F(object[]);
```